# How can I configure poll on check-in for Jenkins against MKS source without building every time?

Tags: jenkins, mks, mks-integrity

We are having an issue when we configure Jenkins to "Poll SCM" with a sechule of every 2 minutes.  It does appear to be polling every 2 minutes, but is also building every 2 minutes instead of only when there are changes to the source.  The "Summary of Changes" for each build includes the same 7 files (updated days ago) for every build.  I don't know if it makes a difference but this is a .net solution with 4 different subprojects.  There is also a folder with dependencies included in the top level polled MKS project directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head for a while it turns out this is due to the movement and/or renaming of file casing in MKS.  MKS does not handle these activities well and I had to locate the phantom entries in the source repository and delete them.  This took care of the problem.